# Android Webservice, REST or SOAP WSDL?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, soap, synchronization

I need to synchonize some data accross different phones. For example I want to enable "friends" to (automatically) share notes...

I'm now wondering what would be the best approch to reach this.

At the moment i think I'll have to write my own webservise to reach this goal.
As I started to think about a SOAP webservice I found lots of people saying that they would prpose a REST approach.

What would be the "better" solution in my case or are there any other approches for synchonizing data on different Android phones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I should start by mentioning that [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is not a protocol and as such hard to compare to [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) which is.

The main disadvantages with using SOAP for mobile applications are that it normally uses XML and thereby more data than most other protocols and that it's fairly complex both to set up and to maintain. On the other hand, if one party writes the server and one the client, SOAP gives you good ways to see to that changes are communicated clearly (ie WSDL). SOAP is generally not very well supported in mobile phones and may require third party libraries to make it work.

REST is often (mis)used as a name for HTTP based communication using JSON, which is a pretty easy way to communicate with mobile devices and has low overhead. If you have control over both server and client, it's not the wrong way to go (but not the only one either) JSON is generally very easy to get to work on all mobile platforms, and HTTP is well supported by the phones themselves.

Comment: I like this answer and just a quick addition: Json is often quicker with regards to ORM, a JSON response can be mapped to objects quicker via libraries likes GSON provided by Google.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use REST than SOAP because SOAP is very verbose and will increase the network data size.

Besides, if you use SOAP, you have to include external librairies (like kSOAP) to consume the response. With REST, a standard HTTP client is OK.

About data format: think about JSON that is less verbose than XML.

Concerning synchronization, I don't know if Android SDK provides classes to perform this work.